# Need a little help understanding this line "[i:i+12]"

Tags: python-3.x

I'm following Automate the Boring Stuff with Python, and I'm doing an exercise that searches for a phone number format (###-###-####) within a group of text. This piece of code is what searches for the pattern: [i:i+12] and I need a little help understanding how it works.

```
def isPhoneNumber(text):
    if len(text) != 12:
        return False
    for i in range(0, 3):
        if not text[i].isdecimal():
            return False
        if text[3] != '-':
            return False
        for i in range(4, 7):
            if not text[i].isdecimal():
                return False
            if text[7] != '-':
                return False
            for i in range(8, 12):
                if not text[i].isdecimal():
                    return False
            return True
message = 'Call me at 415-555-1011 tomorrow. 415-555-9999 is my office.'
for i in range(len(message)):
```

> chunk = message[i:i+12]

```
    if isPhoneNumber(chunk):
        print('Phone number found: ' + chunk)
print('Done')
```

Comment: you mean not understand `chunk = message[i:i+12]`

Answer (score 2):

It is called slice notation, it allows you to *cut out* a bit of an array, you can treat strings a bit like arrays in python.

In your example, when `i=0`, `message[i:i+12]` will be `message[0:12]` this will get the 0th character of the string, up to but not including the 12, so will output `"Call me at 4"`

When `i=1` you will have `message[1:13]` so will get `"all me at 41"`

Effectively you are checking every 12 consecutive characters in the string to see they are a phone number.

You can learn more about slices [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html) (starts talking about slices about halfway into the strings section)